# No kernels installed

Tags: kernel, atom-editor

I am new to Atom. I get the following error message when I try to execute a simple line of JS code.

I have installed the following already:
NPM
Node.JS
Anaconda

[image: The error message]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a kernel installed for the language you want to run (In your case e.g. Javascript. Check out the installation [guide](https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/docs/Installation.html#installation).

Comment: I have already installed Node.js following the link that you provided. Still doesnt work...

Comment: @CharlesLee you need to install javascript, i think it's called IJavascript